# Can't find how to make the php file calculate the average from a received text file that contains more than just numbers

Tags: php, file, calculation

I have a text document that has a set of names and numbers that look like so called grades.txt:

```
Carolyn:Pittman:93
Audrey:Ford:98
Debra:Prince:82
Jeff:Beldsoe:73
Jovante:Price:99
Pat:Clarke:91
Darla:Floyd:82
Charlene:Character:71
Kanji:Grant:83
Langston:Hughes:95
```

I am trying to calculate the average of those grades and display the average.

Here is the code:

```
 <html>
<head><title>Grades Results</title></head>

<body>

<?php
    // create a variable for scores 

    $grade = 0;
    $average = ($grade+$grade+$grade+$grade+$grade+$grade+$grade+$grade+$grade+$grade)/10;
    $highestGrade = 0;

    // open grades.txt data file
    $gradesFile = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    // read first line
    $nextPerson = fgets($gradesFile); // Carolyn:Pittman:93

    while(!feof($gradesFile)){
        list($firstName, $lastName, $grade) = explode(":", $nextPerson);
        print("<p>$firstName</p>");
        print("<p>$lastName:</p>");
        print("<p>$grade</p>");


        $grade = intval($grade);
        // determine if ticket price was highest so far
        if ($grade > $highestGrade){
            $highestGrade = $grade;
            // print("<p>Highest grade $highestGrade </p>");
        } // end if
        // read next line
        $nextPerson = fgets($gradesFile);
    } // end while

    fclose($gradesFile);

    // print the highest price 
    print("<p>The average grade is $average </p>");
    print ("<p>Highest grade was $highestGrade </p>");

?>

</body>
</html>
```

May I have the formula wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calculating the average before you read the file. When you assign to `$average`, `$grade` contains `0`, so you're just averaging 10 values of `0`, which is `0`.

You need to calculate the total during the loop that reads the file, and at the end of the loop calculate the average by dividing by the count of lines that were read.

```
$total = 0;
$count = 0;

while($nextPerson = fgets($gradesFile)){
    list($firstName, $lastName, $grade) = explode(":", $nextPerson);
    print("<p>$firstName</p>");
    print("<p>$lastName:</p>");
    print("<p>$grade</p>");


    $grade = intval($grade);
    // determine if ticket price was highest so far
    if ($grade > $highestGrade){
        $highestGrade = $grade;
        // print("<p>Highest grade $highestGrade </p>");
    } // end if

    $total += $grade;
    $count++;
} // end while

if ($count > 0) {
    $average = $total / $count;
} else {
    $average = 0;
}
```